# Windows : Not able to execute gradle command from groovy script

Tags: windows, gradle, groovy

I am trying to run gradle command from groovy script.
File : file.groovy

```
def command = "gradle clean"
command.execute()
```

Getting following error,

```
$ groovy file.groovy

Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradle": CreateProcess 
error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradle": CreateProcess error=2, The 
system cannot find the file specified
    at file.run(file.groovy:2)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot 
find the file specified
    ... 1 more
```

Same file is running perfectly fine on MAC.

Using Gradle 3.0 and Groovy 2.4.7

Also if running **gradle clean** directly, it is working as expected.

Issues comes only when calling from groovy file on windows system.

Tried on windows cmd as well as cygwin. Same issue.

Comment: Hi Cosmo, did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

> Tried on windows cmd as well as cygwin. Same issue.

I'd say you have a problem with gradle installation. Just follow instructions

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

And pay attention to this point:

> 3.4. Environment variables
>
> For running Gradle, firstly add the environment variable GRADLE_HOME.
>   This should point to the unpacked files from the Gradle website. Next
>   add GRADLE_HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable. Usually, this
>   is sufficient to run Gradle.

Comment: Still not working for me.
`gradle _taskname_` works but
`groovy _groovyScript_` gives the error:
"cannot run program gradle"

Comment: groovy.cmd is not a part of gradle